# How to sum of a double datatype column in Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want this for a windows forms application (vb.net '08).

I want a code for: I have a column called `total` that is of datatype `double` in SQL Server 2005.

How can I sum this field or column in crystal report?

Please give me such kind of help using it I can solve it.......

Comment: You're not giving us enough information and context to be able to help - you should read Jon Skeet's blog post on how to write a good, understandable SO question: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do it. One easy way is to add a formula and then use the Sum function e.g. `sum({yourfield})`.